# Hint for completing Micron level 49

Tags: micron

I would like to have some spoiler-free hints for [Micron](http://microngame.com/) level 49. ([Micron](http://microngame.com/) is a puzzle game available for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apparitiongames.micron), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/micron/id532916819) and [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/290380).)

[image: Animated screenshot of level 49]

I believe I must hit all 4 switches at the same time in order to open the door. But I only have two simultaneous bullets. So I may need to "buffer" some bullets to release 4 at the same time. But maybe I'm just over-thinking.

Don't give me the solution right away! I want some kind of spoiler-free hint, just to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 bullets must exit a portal.

> All 4 bullets must exit at the same time.